# Tempdb. There is no enough space on the disc encountered

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, tempdb

Does anyone know what really happened here?

All of the sudden database was not accessible.

How to find transactions that cause tempdb filled up?

Seems like it happened right after SQL profiler trace has stopped. Can this cause the issue?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you ran out of disc space; that's the real problem.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/how-to-identify-which-query-is-filling-up-the-tempdb-transaction-log

Comment: Just to be clear, your trace is not writing to the same drive your tempdb log file is on is it? That would be an issue on many levels.

Comment: @Larnu, tempdb has 50GB free space. So something filled up all that 50 GB

Comment: Did you have a runaway query ?   For example an ill conceived cross join or many to many ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti No, I did not run such queries